# HTML validation tool

Tags: html

I was watching a video tutorial yesterday and in that, guy was using an HTML error checker that flagged up errors in a panel at the top of the browser screen, much like PHP errors.

This struck me as a useful tool to indicate errors as they occurred during development rather than submitting the site for online validation.

But I can't find such a thing online.

Anyone help?

Comment: Firebug plugin for Firefox?

Comment: Do a search for "HTML validation tool Firefox". Voilá!

Comment: There are also chrome plugins such as [this one](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/html-validator/cgndfbhngibokieehnjhbjkkhbfmhojo?hl=en)

Comment: If you want validate your HTML go [W3C Validator](http://validator.w3.org/), if you want debug your JS codes press Ctrl+Shift+J

Comment: Well I have Firebug but as far as I know it displays the HTML but doesn't validate it. I have the Web Dev toolbar but it uses W3C validation so no good for localhost development. Of course I have searched on Google but still haven't found what I was looking for. So thanks for the responses but they have not mentioned anything new. This is the video I was watching: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0dz4RlwFlUc and at eg about 13m30sec you can see his error notification on his monitor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what was shown in a specific video but these are a few examples you can use:

**Online validator:**

[W3c](http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input)

**Browser validator:**

[Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/nl/firefox/addon/web-developer)

[Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-developer/bfbameneiokkgbdmiekhjnmfkcnldhhm)

Answer (score 0):

Check out [W3C](http://validator.w3.org/)

Additionally you can use firefox with [Web Developer Tool Bar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/web-developer/)

Also you can find many useful extensions for firefox.

Finally most powerful tools are IDEs, there are many of them out there...